# Get length of values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to get the length of each zipCd value in the dataframe mentioned below.  When I run the code below I get 958 for every record.  I'm expecting to get something more like '4'.  Does anyone see what the issue is?

```
Code:
zipDfCopy['zipCd'].str.len()

Data:
print zipDfCopy[1:5]

   Zip Code  Place Name          State State Abbreviation     County  \
1       544  Holtsville       New York                 NY    Suffolk   
2      1001      Agawam  Massachusetts                 MA    Hampden   
3      1002     Amherst  Massachusetts                 MA  Hampshire   
4      1003     Amherst  Massachusetts                 MA  Hampshire   

   Latitude  Longitude                                              zipCd  
1   40.8154   -73.0451  0          501\n1          544\n2         1001...  
2   42.0702   -72.6227  0          501\n1          544\n2         1001...  
3   42.3671   -72.4646  0          501\n1          544\n2         1001...  
4   42.3919   -72.5248  0          501\n1          544\n2         1001...
```

Comment: your running this on the column `zipCd` which looks to have the values `1001...` which implies that the length of the string is far greater than 4.  Those ellipses mean that the string was longer that the width of the columns and Pandas put ellipses there instead of displaying  the whole string.  Either you are using the wrong column or your data is messed up.

Answer (score 21):

One way is to convert to string and use `pd.Series.map` with `len` built-in.

[`pd.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) is used for vectorized string functions, while [`pd.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) is used to change column type.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ZipCode': [341, 4624, 536, 123, 462, 4642]})

df['ZipLen'] = df['ZipCode'].astype(str).map(len)

#    ZipCode  ZipLen
# 0      341       3
# 1     4624       4
# 2      536       3
# 3      123       3
# 4      462       3
# 5     4642       4
```

A more explicit alternative is to use `np.log10`:

```
df['ZipLen'] = np.floor(np.log10(df['ZipCode'].values)).astype(int) + 1
```

Comment: thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  When I tried astype it still gave me 958 for every record.  This worked correctly though: zipDfCopy['Zip Code'].apply(str).map(len)

Comment: OK, that's strange - if you want to convert a column of integers to strings `df[col].astype(str)` certainly works, so there may be an issue with your data types.